# Apexcharts bar chart not appearing in Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, apexcharts

im trying to create a chart for my vue.js site using [Apexcharts](https://apexcharts.com/) however my chart isnt appearing at all.

-Apexcharts documentation [Here](https://apexcharts.com/docs/installation/#)

**HTML**

```
  <div class="section sec2"> 
    <div id="chart"></div>
    {{chart}} <--failed attempt
  </div>
...
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'
export default {
  // name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {//////////this is how i use global variable with vue.js///////////////
    width:{           type: String, default: function(){return('width:')}},
  }
}
var options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'sales',
    data: [30,40,45,50,49,60,70,91,125]
  }],
  xaxis: {
    categories: [1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997, 1998,1999]
  }
}

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();

</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
  @import '../assets/style/sec.css';
#chart {
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 35px auto;
}

</style>
```

i tried using the vue.js global variable by turning "var option = ..." into "option:...", but it only gave me an error.

im pretty sure its supossed to show in the div with the "#chart" id

any helpand or advice is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**: This answer was written when vue-apexcharts wrapper was not released. If you're looking for a better example on Vue integration with ApexCharts, check out https://github.com/apexcharts/vue-apexcharts

---

ApexCharts documentation currently doesn't have an example on how to use it with Vue/React, therefore I will try to provide a simple demo to use ApexCharts in Vue.js.

Here is the HTML Part

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="chart" ref="barchart"></div>
</div>
```

and here is the JS part

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted: function() {
    const chart = new ApexCharts(this.$refs.barchart, {
      chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 400
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'sales',
        data: [30,40,45,50,49,60,70,91,125]
      }],
      xaxis: {
        categories: [1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997, 1998,1999]
      }
    })

    chart.render();

  }
});
```

ApexCharts just require a reference to the DOM element, whether it is in Vue/React to render the chart on the screen. In the above code, I have referenced the DOM element via this.$refs.

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/WKzyaN) link for the example I gave above

Comment: i replaced my code with yours to fix it and it gave me a couple errors, i added the '
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js' ' import and it fix most of them but now its giving me this error in the chrome console that is posted in the bellow coment

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined

Comment: Working. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer saved my day!